# Protocol Handler with multiple paramters

Tags: c#, windows

I've set up a Protocol Handler in the registry and everything works fine. I can use the protocol and send a single parameter to a C# console app, great.

What I can't do however is have the C# app interpret the protocol data as multiple parameters. I've tried the following but have had no luck:

> Protocol Link for MyProtocol = "C:\test.exe" "%1" "%2"
>
> Call = MyProtocol://1 2

But all I get is one parameter with the 1, space character and the 2. What I need is to send multiple parameters, this would make my life easier.

If I have to just interpret the one parameter then fine, it's not the nicest way forward though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to parse this yourself, a protocol handler defines a uri which has no intrinsic knowledge of how to pass more than one argument to the executable its linked to, so you get the whole thing in `args[0]` (including `protocolname:`).

The obvious format is `MyProtocol://doathing/1/2`

Which you can parse:

```
var uri = new Uri("MyProtocol://doAthing/1/2", UriKind.Absolute);
if (uri.Scheme == "myprotocol") {
    if (uri.Authority == "doathing") {
        var argsArray = uri.PathAndQuery.Split(new [] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        //...
    }
}
```

Or implement your own `UriParser` subclass.