# C# Pass Argument to application in hyperlink

Tags: c#, hyperlink, arguments

How do I pass an argument to an application via a hyperlink.  I've figured out how to pull an argument into my C# application using this code:

```
String[] CMDlineargs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            string[] strArray = CMDlineargs.ToArray<string>();

                if (strArray.Length >1)
                {
                strCommandLineArg = strArray[1];
                MessageBox.Show("Argument is: " + strCommandLineArg);
            }
            else
            {
                strCommandLineArg = "";
            }
```

But I haven't figured out how to pass the argument to the application in a hyperlink yet.  It's simple to pass an argument to the application in a file explorer window.  Simply enter the file path with a space then the argument.  I thought it would be that simple in a hyperlink, but I always get a "can't find file" error when I try to execute the hyperlink by clicking on it when it has the argument in it.

I expected the argument to simply pass to the application from the hyperlink but clicking on my hyperlink always produces an error.  FYI I do not want a Protocol link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protocol Handler with multiple paramters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783325/protocol-handler-with-multiple-paramters)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either.  They were using "...MyApplication.exe" "%2" in their example.  I tried it with the percent symbol and it throws the same error.  I tried it on my C drive and on a shared server with no luck.